# defining both client and server in main

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am new to Java Socket programming. I try to use NIO socket. I follow some code on client and server side. I can use each of them separately. but when I use both in main, Just the first on will start. I want to know first if it it is logical to doing this and second how I can manage this problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 NioSocketServer server = new NioSocketServer();
 NioSocketClient client = new NioSocketClient();
```

Comment: what is the point of having both the server and client in one function?
and if there is a point to it, you cannot do this, the client and the server must be at least in different threads!

Comment: OK, I am going to write a module which will be inserted between two other machine (they're communicating right now), so I want to play the server role  for the client side and meanwhile the client role for the server side of amy already network. so I take the message from server for example, I will do some change on it and after that I send it to the client

Comment: so you will create a ServerSocket for doing the first thing, so when the first machine connects, it connects to your ServerSocket, and inside that Socket you open another Socket to send info to the second machine, while there is another ServerSocket open on that second machine

Comment: yes, exactly this scenario

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ServerSocket (or NioSocketServer as you need) :

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
Socket client = server.accept();
// get data from client
// do your processing here and then 
// make your reponse into a String msg
Socket secondMachine = new Socket(secondMachineAddress, secondMachinePort);
secondMachine.getOutputStream().write(msg.getBytes()); // something like this!
secondMachine.getOutputStream().flush();
```

of course the code is just a schema and it is only to give you an idea how it is done, it won't work (or compile!).

Comment: the problem comes from this fact that in NIO when you define new AsynchronousSocketChannel or AsynchronousServerSocketChannel, you should define separate CompletionHandler for each and so you can't define them easily.

Comment: well you didn't mention this as a part of your question so how would I know!?